# Upgrade client to be ACMEv2 compatible

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, certbot

Ubuntu
Nginx
Cloudflare

I followed instructions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/let-s-encrypt-acmev1-protocol-you-should-upgrade-to-an-acmev2.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install –only-upgrade certbot
```

This has updated certbot from 0.27.0 to 0.31.0.

and downloaded this: `/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org`

Updated after comment:

But there is no `/etc/letsencrypt/acme.sh` script, do I need one?

But essentially I think I need to know is this certbot client ACME2 compatible?

Comment: It looks like the the source of `acme.sh` is [here](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh), but it appears to be a client to use instead of `certbot`.  If `certbot` is working for you, you should not need `acme.sh`.

Comment: Thank you, I wondered what the relationship between acme and certbot was.